# Why isn't autotest working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, autotest, zentest

I'm trying to use autotest for Rails development. It's supposed to run my tests automatically.

Here's my setup:

```
$ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby

$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0]

$ rails -v
Rails 2.3.9

autotest-rails (4.1.0)
ZenTest (4.4.0)

$ echo $PATH
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Users/ethan/bin:/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/pgsql/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/oracle/instantclient_10_2
```

Here's the gem environment:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-10
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8
     - /Users/ethan/.gem/ruby/1.8
     - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - :sources => ["http://gemcutter.org"]
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://gemcutter.org
```

Here's the error. It looks like autotest is trying to use some other version of Ruby.

```
$ autotest
loading autotest/rails
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby -I.:lib:test -rubygems -e "%w[test/unit test/functional/procurements_controller_test.rb].each { |f| require f }" | unit_diff -u
sh: /usr/local/bin/unit_diff: /usr/local/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/test/unit/ui/console/testrunner.rb:108:in `flush': Broken pipe (Errno::EPIPE)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/test/unit/ui/console/testrunner.rb:108:in `output'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/test/unit/ui/console/testrunner.rb:51:in `setup_mediator'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/test/unit/ui/console/testrunner.rb:39:in `start'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/test/unit/ui/testrunnerutilities.rb:29:in `run'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/test/unit/autorunner.rb:216:in `run'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/test/unit/autorunner.rb:12:in `run'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/test/unit.rb:278
    from -e:1
```

Comment: Post your $PATH please? And any scripts involved.

Comment: Please add the output of `gem env` also. We need to see what Gems thinks its environment is.

Answer (score 2):

I see two things:

Your `which ruby` says the default is `/usr/bin/ruby`, but your Autotest is calling `/usr/local/bin/ruby`.

> sh: /usr/local/bin/unit_diff: /usr/local/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Also, your path is not organized well because you have duplicated entries. I split it on ':' then sorted it to look for duplicates:

```
/bin
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin
/opt/local/bin # <--
/opt/local/bin # <--
/opt/local/sbin
/sbin
/Users/ethan/bin
/usr/bin
/usr/local/bin # <--
/usr/local/bin # <--
/usr/local/git/bin
/usr/local/mysql/bin
/usr/local/oracle/instantclient_10_2
/usr/local/pgsql/bin
/usr/sbin
```

Notice that you have duplicated `/opt/local/bin` and `/usr/local/bin` directories. Those should appear ahead of the default `/usr/bin` directory in order for your "personally" installed apps to be located first, so you should do some housekeeping. Once you have done that close your terminal session(s). Open a new session and try rerunning your test and see if anything has changed/improved.

The path organization is part of the problem and explains why `which ruby` points to the system Ruby. I suspect another part of this puzzle is that you are using `#!/usr/local/bin/ruby` as the "bang slash" in your scripts, or explicitly pointing to that Ruby when you call things on the command-line. That will confuse tests no end. In my scripts I use this to invoke Ruby:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

which works nicely because it uses whatever Ruby is defined first in my path, and with this next part...

I'm a big proponent for using [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com) to manage Ruby installations on Mac OS and Linux. It makes it so you don't have to install anything in your default `/usr/bin` ruby or even bother with adding one in `/usr/local/bin`. RVM puts everything in `~/.rvm` and makes it really easy to install/manage/remove Ruby versions along with their associated gems, or even blow it all away by deleting that directory. [Installing RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/) and [Gemsets](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/gemsets/) are good starting places if you want to give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Greg. I cleaned up my path. I added gem environment output. Tried autotest again. Now I get "Autotest style autotest/rails doesn't seem to exist. Aborting." Not sure if that's better or worse.

Comment: BTW, RVM sounds great. Maybe I'll try it.

Answer (score 1):

Rails support seems out of the ZenTest core. Install `autotest-rails` or downgrade to ZenTest 4.0.0 to have it working again.

Comment: It's a  known feature. In first place I have incidentally submitted a partial answer. The answer is now as complete as my knowledge permits.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did have autotest-rails installed (take a look at original post). However, I tried downgrading to ZenTest 4.0.0. Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the following to get my autotest working after getting the following error with ruby ree-1.8.7 + rbenv: "rbenv: autotest: command not found" even though gem said autotest was installed. The binary in /usr/local/rbenv/versions/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/bin/autotest was missing however, even after repeated reinstalls of autotest.

```
#> gem uninstall ZenTest #all versions
#> gem uninstall autotest autotest-fsevent autotest-growl autotest-rails
#> bundle install
```

My Gemfile:

```
group :test,:development do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.0'
  gem 'mocha','~> 0.12.1', :require => false #for mocking data
  gem 'ZenTest', '4.8.2' #DON'T USE 4.8.3 with Rails 3.2!
  gem 'autotest', '~> 4.4.6'
  gem 'autotest-fsevent','~> 0.2.8'
  gem 'autotest-rails', '~> 4.1.2'
  gem 'autotest-growl', '~> 0.2.16'
end
```